# React/Redux mapStateToProps with nested JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a redux component that is parsing the JSON (at bottom), but I can't figure out how to grab the nested child objects. I don't think I'm understanding correctly how mapStateToProps works.

The console log is dumping the child objects, but when I try to access services.name I get

`"Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"`

Can someone help me understand how to map properties here? I've included an example of the JSON I'm grabbing from the API at the bottom.

services-list.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';

class ServicesList extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.fetchServices();
  }

  render() {
    //console.log('render called in ServicesList component');
    return (
      <table className='table table-hover'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Service Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.props.services.map(this.renderServices)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }

  renderServices(data) {
    console.log(data.services);
    const name = data.services.name;
    return(
      <tr key={name}>
        <td>{name}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({services}) {
  return { services };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(ServicesList);
```

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "services": [
     {
        "name": "redemption-service",
        "versions": {
            "desired": "20170922_145033",
            "deployed": "20170922_145033"
        },
        "version": "20170922_145033"
    }, {
        "name": "client-service",
        "versions": {
            "desired": "20170608_094954",
            "deployed": "20170608_094954"
        },
        "version": "20170608_094954"
    }, {
        "name": "content-rules-service",
        "versions": {
            "desired": "20170922_130454",
            "deployed": "20170922_130454"
        },
        "version": "20170922_130454"
    }
  ]
}
```

Finally, I have an action that exposes the axios.get here:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const ROOT_URL=`http://localhost:8080/services.json`;

export const FETCH_SERVICES = 'FETCH_SERVICES';

export function fetchServices(){
  const url = `${ROOT_URL}`;
  const request = axios.get(url);

  return{
    type: FETCH_SERVICES,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

Comment: your `const name = data.services.name;` should be `const name = data.name;`

Comment: That is bcoz, your are mapping over `services` and for each loop you get a single `service` in `renderServices` function.

Comment: Correct, it is calling renderServices exactly once. What I don't understand is how to map the next object down when it's not named.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you think `this.props.fetchServices()` will update the `services` reducer and then will pass the `services` as a prop via the `mapStateToProps`.
If this is correct, note that you are fetching inside `componentWillMount` and this is a **BIG** no no.
Quote from the [`componentWillMount` DOCS](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount):

> Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method.

You should fetch data in `componentDidMount`.

In addition, you probably think the render method won't invoked until you got your data back from the ajax request. You see, react won't wait for your ajax call to get back with the data, the `render` method will be invoked no matter what, so the first `render` call will try to `map` on an empty array of `services` (you got an empty array as initial state in your reducer i assume).
Then your `renderServices` function will get an empty array as `data` and `data.services` is indeed `undefined` hence when you try to access `data.services.name` you get the error:

> "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Just use a condition in your render:

```
<tbody>
  {this.props.services && this.props.services.map(this.renderServices)}
</tbody>
```

**Edit**
As a followup to your comment, you are trying to map on an `object` but `.map` works on arrays. so actually you should map on `services.services.map(...)` instead of `services.map`, Though you still need to check if it's exists.
I've made a working example with your code, i did not include redux and ajax requests but i used the same data you are using and i'm passing it only on the second render of `ServicesList`, so it basically has the same scenario you are facing.
I've even added a timeout to mimic a delay + added a loading indicator to demonstrate what you can (or should) do with conditional rendering.

```js
const fakeData = {
  services: [
    {
      name: "redemption-service",
      versions: {
        desired: "20170922_145033",
        deployed: "20170922_145033"
      },
      version: "20170922_145033"
    },
    {
      name: "client-service",
      versions: {
        desired: "20170608_094954",
        deployed: "20170608_094954"
      },
      version: "20170608_094954"
    },
    {
      name: "content-rules-service",
      versions: {
        desired: "20170922_130454",
        deployed: "20170922_130454"
      },
      version: "20170922_130454"
    }
  ]
};

class ServicesList extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchServices();
  }

  render() {
    const { services } = this.props;

    return (
      <table className="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Service Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {services.services ? (
            services.services.map(this.renderServices)
          ) : (
            this.renderLoader()
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }

  renderLoader() {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>Loading...</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }

  renderServices(data) {
    const name = data.name;
    return (
      <tr key={name}>
        <td>{name}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {}
    };
    this.fetchServices = this.fetchServices.bind(this);
  }

  fetchServices() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ data: { ...fakeData } });
    }, 1500);
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <ServicesList services={data} fetchServices={this.fetchServices} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Okay, I updated to send the fetch in a componentDidMount instead, but the same issue remains... the data comes back (I can see the entire 30 records being logged) but I just don't know how to map because the JSON has a single top level record. Question was, how do I skip the top record and map the children.

Comment: the `componentDidMount`  was not the solution, i just mentioned it because it's bad practice to do it with `componentWillMount`. I've updated my answer with more explanation and a working example, i think this should set you on the right path. :)